# Opera NOT executing flexslider

Tags: jquery, performance, flexslider

Doesnt matter what I do, whilst loading Flexslider on the home page on Opera it wont load/execute Flexsider to display ANYTHING.

The Flexslider works/executes on chrome firefox and safari, Both on pc and mac, also iphone ipad and nexus 7.

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

I have changed this around 6 7 time now and still nothing. It loads the images for the next and previous images but no such content decided to load.

Literally no idea why Opera wont display it.

I decided to test the site on opera mini on the ipad and it loaded the slider with the images but was slow.

I am loading images through json.

EDIT: If anyone is interested in the link to the site, its password protected atm but am willing to give access to get this problem that I cant seem to shift gone

Comment: Is there any error reported in dragonfly?

Comment: If you give us the error, maybe no access to your site will be needed.

Comment: Im getting no errors at all. I really dont like Opera at all and hardly ever use it. Whats the best way to see if theres any errors in Opera dev tools?

Comment: From what i can see, its not loading the <UL> that is being appended in my jquery.

Comment: @gustavohenke I have installed a second flexslider with stand alone images, NOT json loaded images. it works with stand alone images, IT MUST BE MY JQUERY IMAGES that are being loaded in but not loading or something